# Unexpected behaviour of String.fromCodePoint / String#codePointAt (Firefox/ES6)

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, utf-8, utf-16

Since version 29 of Firefox, Mozilla provides the [String.fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) and [String#codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) methods and also published polyfills on the respective MDN pages.

So it happens that I am currently trying this out and it seems that I am missing something important, as splitting the string "ä☺" into codepoints and reassembling it from these returns an, at least for me, unexpected result.

I've built a test case: http://jsfiddle.net/dcodeIO/YhwP7/

```
var str = "ä☺";
...split it, reassemble it...
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem of `.codePointAt`, but more of the char encoding of the character .  has a javascript string length of 2.

**Why?**
Because Javascript Strings are encoded using 2-byte UTF-16.  ( charcode: 132878 ) is greater than 2-byte UTF-16 ( 0-65535 ). This means it needs to be encoded using 4-byte UTF-16. Its UTF-16 representation is `0xD841 0xDF0E` consuming two characters in the string.

When using `.charAt()` you will see the correct values:

```
var string = "";
console.log( string.charAt(0), string.charAt(1) ); // logs 55361 57102 (0xD841 0xDF0E)
```

**Why doesn't it display `228, 9786, 55361, 57102`?**
Thats because `.codePointAt()` converts 4-byte UTF-16 characters to integers correctly ( `132878` ).

**So why does it output `57,102` then?**
Because you are iterating for `str.length` in your loop, which returns 4 (because `"".length == "`), so `.codePointAt()` will get executed on `str[3]` which is `57102`.

Comment: Thank you for your precise explanation!What would you suggest to do instead of iterating over str.length, if the goal remains to extract all valid code points?

Comment: You could use a for..of loop, which will do the right thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Like so? (Just want to make sure not to do something stupid again)

while (i < str.length) {
            arr.push(cp = str.codePointAt(i));
            i += cp < 0xFFFF ? 1 : 2;
        }

Comment: yeah thats nice, should even have a better performance than the for-loop ;)

Comment: that's the correct answer, you can also follow the (~~) inner-logic using the [*Polyfill* example at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint#Polyfill)